# Uptime proof for your Loki Network Service Node?

Tags: monero-forks, loki, service-node

Is there a way to check the uptime of my Loki Network Service node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the telegram bot to monitor your loki service node: Message on telegram: **@LokiSNBot**

Or do it via the website: https://lokiblocks.com/  -- You can get your Service Node pub key on the command line with: **./lokid print_sn_status**